# Função para popular TTreeview só adiciona childs ao primeiro node

Tags: delphi, pascal, object-pascal, treeview

Criei essa `procedure` para popular um treeview:

```
procedure TFrmGerProfDock.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
Tables: TTreeNode;
I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to ds.DataSet.FieldCount - 1 do
  begin
    TreeView1.Items.BeginUpdate;
    TreeView1.Items.Add(nil, ds.DataSet.Fields[I].FieldName); //adiciona um node novo
    while not ds.DataSet.Eof do
    begin
      TreeView1.Items.AddChild(TreeView1.Items[I],
        ds.DataSet.Fields[I].AsString);//adiciona ao node novos childs
      ds.DataSet.Next;
    end;
    ds.DataSet.First;
    TreeView1.Items.EndUpdate;

  end;
end;
```

O problema é que a `procedure` sempre adiciona os childs no primeiro node, o que estaria errado neste meu código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa guardar a referência do Node pai, use a variável `Tables` que você criou.

```
Var
  Tables: TTreeNode;
  Root : TTreeNode;
  I: Integer;
begin
  TreeView1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  //Incluir Root
  Root := TreeView1.Items.Add(nil, 'Root'); 
  for I := 0 to ds.DataSet..FieldCount - 1 do
  begin
    // Guarde o node Pai
    Tables := TreeView1.Items.Add(Root, ds.DataSet..Fields[I].FieldName);                
    //adiciona um node novo
    while not ClientDataset1.Eof do
    begin
      //Aqui você inclui no pai
      TreeView1.Items.AddChild(Tables,
        ds.DataSet..Fields[I].AsString);//adiciona ao node novos childs
      ds.DataSet..Next;
    end;
    ds.DataSet..First;   
  end;
  TreeView1.Items.EndUpdate; //O Begin e End update não podem ficar dentro de um loop, isso faz eles ficaram piscando.
end;
```

Comment: Exato, o problema é que eles ficam todos nodes separados sem um root, tem como eu criar um node e colocar todos eles dentro?

Comment: Veja meu edit..

Comment: Valeu mesmo, obrigado.